# Cannot save the attachment. There is not enough free memory to run this program. Quit one or more programs, and then try again

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2010

I am getting the following exception when i am trying to save mail attachment .

Code :

```
if (attachmentType == OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem)
{
    var at = mailItem.Attachments[1];
    at.SaveAsFile(tempMsgFile); // Exception is thrown here.

    actualEmail = outlookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(tempMsgFile, tempFolder) as MailItem;
}
```

I am getting the below exception

> System.OutOfMemoryException occurred   HResult=-2147024882
>   Message=Cannot save the attachment. There is not enough free memory to
>   run this program. Quit one or more programs, and then try again.
>   Source=Microsoft Outlook   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment.SaveAsFile(String Path)
>   InnerException:

When I try to save mail as msg file from outlook itself , then also I am getting the same exception.

I don't notice any memory issues, and this error occurs for some emails only. What I have noticed is emails for which the above error occurs have many To addresses.

Any clue??

Comment: Can you save (MailItem.SaveAs) the parent message in the olMsg format? How about olMsgUnicode?

Comment: No, I can't save the parent message in both unicode and non unicode format.

Comment: What kind of message store (PST, OST, etc.) are you using? How many recipient does the message have?

Comment: It's PST and the no of recipients is 913